# Could you explain why @Html.DisplayFor(x=>x) yields the same result as @Html.DisplayForModel()?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

### Question:

1. Could you explain why `@Html.DisplayFor(x=>x)` yields the same result as `@Html.DisplayForModel()` in the following scenario?
2. When do they produce different result?

**Model**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace MvcMusicStore.Models
{
    public class Genre
    {
        public int GenreId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public List<Album> Albums { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using MvcMusicStore.Models;

namespace MvcMusicStore.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        MusicStoreEntities db = new MusicStoreEntities();
        //
        // GET: /Home/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var genres = db.Genres.ToList();
            return View(genres);
        }
     }
}
```

**Index.cshtml View**

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcMusicStore.Models.Genre>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

@Html.DisplayFor(x=>x)
```

or

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcMusicStore.Models.Genre>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>


@Html.DisplayForModel()
```

**Shared/DisplayTemplates/Genre.cshtml**

```
@model MvcMusicStore.Models.Genre

<fieldset>
    <legend>Genre</legend>

    <div class="display-label">Name</div>
    <div class="display-field">@Model.Name</div>

    <div class="display-label">Description</div>
    <div class="display-field">@Model.Description</div>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [**`DisplayForModel()`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.displayextensions.displayformodel.aspx) method returns HTML markup for *each property in the model.*

The [**`DisplayFor()`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.displayextensions.displayfor%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) method returns HTML markup for *each property in the object that is represented by the Lambda Expression you provide.*

So when you say `DisplayFor(x => x)`, your expression says, *"use the entire model,"*  which gives you the same result as `DisplayForModel()`.

A demonstration Visual Studio project illustrating DisplayFor() is available [here.](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=158686)