# How do I pass the model into a template in MVC 4?

Tags: templates, asp.net-mvc-4, model

I'm trying to do the following in MVC 4:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x, "QCDetailDepartmentTable-ActionButton")
```

When I step through the code, it completely bypasses the template and won't display anything.

However, if I replace this with a field in the model, like:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.SortOrder, "QCDetailDepartmentTable-ActionButton")
```

it works just fine.

The template file that I have simply has:

```
<td>hi</td>
```

Any ideas why trying to pass the model doesn't work?

Comment: Try specifying the model type in your template with `@model YourModelClass`

Comment: I tried that too.  It still doesn't work.

Comment: If you want to display a template for the whole model use `@Html.DisplayForModel("QCDetailDepartmentTable-ActionButton")`

Comment: The `DisplayFor()` method returns HTML markup for each property in the object that is represented by the Lambda Expression you provide. [Check this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4917647/1551730)